# Onclick with check box

Tags: javascript

I have a check box which calls a js function like so :

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="return validate('tos')" value="1" name="tos"/>
```

But i am having a problem with the JS detecting when it is infact unticked it seems to always return true.

This is how i have my script:

```
function validate(type){

    var x = document.getElementById("reg"); //get array of elements in form "reg"
    var input = x.elements[4].value; //[4] = checkbox

    if(input){
        alert('ticked');    
    } else {
        alert('not ticked');    
    }
}
```

But it always returns ticked, even if the user clicks it when it was already ticked (which i thought would mean it was not the value of 1 anymore)... is there a way i can fix that in JS ?

Comment: the `value` of the checkbox is always `1`. Try testing with `.checked` for the checked attribute instead of the `value` one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `value` of the checkbox is always `1`, independently of its `checked` state.

Use the  `.checked` property to get the checkbox's checked state.

Comment: No prob. :) Glad to be of help.